# How to move control strip on mac touchbar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Is there a way to mirror the control strip on the touch-bar to have the volume controls on the left instead of the right?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change Touch Bar icons press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and type keyboard then press  <kbd>enter</kbd>. It will open to the Keyboard pane in System Preferences.

Then click the Customize Control Strip… button and from there and you can drag icons down or move down your mouse pointer to select and drag icons from or to elsewhere on the Touch Bar.

Note that if your Touch Bar is collapsed, touch the < on it to expand it before modifying it.

Comment: Also there is an app called Better Touch tool that allows an astonishingly broad selection of customizations, if you want to go that route: https://folivora.ai/downloads